# YouTube API search URL encoding with multiple words

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm making a chrome extension that utilizes the YouTube Data API. I'm doing a simple query for keywords, and then creating embed links from the response.

I'm having trouble encoding the GET url. Mine looks something like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=laughing...
```

When the query is one word, everything works great. But if I want to search for 'baby laughing', I can't seem to encode correctly. This link (https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#qsp) says multiple word queries need to be URL escaped, which makes sense, but its not working as expected.

neither

```
...q=baby+laughing...
```

nor

```
...q=baby%20laughing...
```

Anyone know whats going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly is not working?

This

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=baby+laughing
```

is working for me.

Comment: Hi, turns out my response was coming back 200 but empty, which makes no sense. It now works...Thanks.